# Loose Type definition with Omit and [key:string]: unknown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I post code first explain after :

```js
type ExampleType = {
  a: string;
  b: boolean;
  c: () => any;
  d?: boolean;
  e?: () => any;
  [inheritsProps: string]: unknown;
  // If this ^ line over is remove, TypeNoC would work as I expect, but without a loose definition
};

type TypeNoC = Omit<ExampleType, "c">
// TypeNoC == {}
```

Some months ago, I was searching a way to define React Props allowing any other properties while still keeping only the essential define. Reason was that our props type were extends with React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement| HTMLButtonElement | ...> but when trying to use the component, you get 200+ optional properties mixed with the Required properties. That's annoying and not helpful, so I found this solution : `[inheritsProps: string]: unknown;` which said that any other props define would be valid even if they aren't define in typing.

Now I'm working on a component with a controlled and uncontrolled version and I would like to remove some definition of the controlled version for the uncontrolled definition. Uncontrolled is using the controlled component and try to simplify how you use it. So I would like to remove some of the required properties. I would expect that `Omit<ExampleType, "c">` should make a type that c is no more {a,b,d,e,...} while still c could exist because of `[key:string]:unknown`, but that is not the current case. The current case is that TypeNoC has no properties... I think it's a bug, but I'm not sure if I'm using the feature properly in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that TypeScript's `Omit<T, K>` utility type doesn't really work well when `T` has an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).  I'd say this is just a limitation of `Omit` and not really a *bug*.

---

The [definition of `Omit<T, K>` in TypeScript's library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ec1490fb4468b6448c5869446d17e570c13c51d6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1504) is

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

where `Pick<T, K>` is [defined as](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ec1490fb4468b6448c5869446d17e570c13c51d6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1480-L1482)

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]: T[P]; };
```

and `Exclude<T, U>` is  [defined as](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ec1490fb4468b6448c5869446d17e570c13c51d6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1494)

```
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T
```

---

When `T` is a type with only known keys like `{a: string, b: number}`, then `Omit` behaves as expected. But when `T` also has a `string` index signature like `ExampleType` then `keyof T` will be the union of `string | number` ([why `number`?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types)) with all the known [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) keys like `"a"` and `"b"`.  But the union of `string | number` with any string or numeric literal like `"a"` or `1` is just `string | number`, because string or numeric literals don't add any new possibilities to `string | number`:

```
type KeyofExampleType = keyof ExampleType; // string | number
```

And so `Exclude<keyof ExampleType, "c">` becomes `Exclude<string | number, "c">` which, if you follow the [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) definition of `Exclude`, is also just `string | number`: you can't express "all `string`s except for `"c"` in TypeScript; it's just `string`.

And *that* means that `Omit<ExampleType, "c">` becomes `Pick<ExampleType, string | number>`, which just produces the `string`/`number` indexes of `ExampleType` and *completely omits all known keys*:

```
type BadTypeNoC = Omit<ExampleType, "c">
/* type BadTypeNoC = {
    [x: string]: unknown;
    [x: number]: unknown;
} */
```

(this is not `{}` as you claim in your question, though... you should double check that because I can't reproduce it)

---

Could `Omit` be implemented differently so as to act "properly" for types with index signatures? (and are we really sure what "properly" means? there might be edge cases).  Well, maybe, but with *considerably more effort* and producing a much more complicated definition.

First you need a way to express something *like* `keyof ExampleType` that gives you the *known* literal keys and not just the wider `string` and `number` index types.  This can be done using conditional type inference, as mentioned [in this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25987#issuecomment-408339599), but it's crazy/ugly/surprising:

```
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;

type KnownPart<T> = Pick<T, KnownKeys<T>>
```

So `KnownKeys<ExampleType>` is `"a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e"`, and `KnownPart<ExampleType>` is just the `ExampleType` type without its index signatures.  Analogously, you can come up with the index-signature keys and index-signature part:

```
type IndexableKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? K : number extends K ? K : never
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;
type IndexPart<T> = Pick<T, IndexableKeys<T>>
```

Finally, you can make a version of `Omit<T, K>` that splits `T` into its `KnownPart` and its `IndexPart` and performs the key exclusion on each part, and then joins them back together:

```
type Omitʹ<T, K extends PropertyKey> = 
  Omit<KnownPart<T>, K> & Omit<IndexPart<T>, K> extends
  infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

That produces the expected `TypeNoC`, I think:

```
type TypeNoC = Omitʹ<ExampleType, "c">
/* type TypeNoC = {
    [x: string]: unknown;
    a: string;
    b: boolean;
    d?: boolean | undefined;
    e?: (() => any) | undefined;
} */
```

---

If you want to use something like `Omitʹ` instead of `Omit` in your code, you should feel free.  But the reason why such a definition is not provided in the standard library is probably that it is way too complex and has too many potential points of failure.  The benefits of being able to handle indexable types are probably not worth it, especially because indexable types are less common.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCrmgXigbwFgAoKKBALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbhLICMquB7PugRMOpKAGMqACgCUUHAD5yTEKLIATAPy8BQkZygRtUWfKXDVBgNrMAFhEbBqABTp8w1KrUasAulQBXJgBrJj4Ad31iAF9RElBIKABpCBA+ADN4ZDRMbHkoYNSM2EQUdCxINigAemqaemYWKAAfKCYApC4HEh7iBOgAIQR1CogAOT4AYXyAeSQGYAAeLLLcyAAaKAAicS2FEmqAKih+qCGR7AnpvCIxMis4Lwa-QJCwyLUyKAeqds6HfxQIKhCJRaJQQ7VXrxPJJd5MFIgaiLDBKG7WJJQZgFIrpKAYQHeRqGODACBMdTUZJQTRtCAANwcUF+HS6dBJZIpVMxtKYDKZVCSJHBEFJ5MpBG+AH0sUwcWk8QSqMx0kyAKpQcG0jW-fl0USnOGg5wIOhLVH5ZwMcTBFGbI2RRHI1H7YgwxIASQpooQXHQTpRaIIGNl8uKSvqPiaos5Ep51JZ-3ZMfF3JpCbpjLowo5qclVhl2MKCvxgJV6s16Z1mYcVXd0C96lFJrNgct1ttGE2jZ9fogAZdvVOcwWgE6gO3UlNcqCudwOUCIoMjpYOpgt80Ke1KABkUGXix7cHXga3ua5BnL7Jm6fw32coeLxRmgJmVmcvkruqzcTdfVh8KdFYclGfJVwDIDymwV1ahOf9QUA0pgLyPAtgQLYWm2Lh0NaHZsO2dQ8K2CAtmhX9TlGK5ZnmYBxwgtYIE2XDoOOcjLimfJbi+b5HkjRpAWBeFPjISheNYISoB4CTdAgYRxK0HRBBkuVWiCJt0mYCB1HEoxpFMRRlBAOQVO9dS+S0nNISAA)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @jcalz's great answer above, I'll just note that I found the following in MongoDB's source [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/b67af3cd/src/mongo_types.ts#L45-L50):

```js
/** TypeScript Omit (Exclude to be specific) does not work for objects with an "any" indexed type, and breaks discriminated unions @public */
export type EnhancedOmit<TRecordOrUnion, KeyUnion> = string extends keyof TRecordOrUnion
  ? TRecordOrUnion // TRecordOrUnion has indexed type e.g. { _id: string; [k: string]: any; } or it is "any"
  : TRecordOrUnion extends any
  ? Pick<TRecordOrUnion, Exclude<keyof TRecordOrUnion, KeyUnion>> // discriminated unions
  : never;
```

which is used in the same file for things like:

```js
export type WithId<TSchema> = EnhancedOmit<TSchema, '_id'> & { _id: InferIdType<TSchema> };
```

and works just as well for `unknown` type.